# Cant install express on Windows

Tags: node.js, express

I have been trying to install express dependencies for a few hours now and can't seem to get it working. I used the express generator downloaded with `npm install express-generator -g` and get an error related to privileges. I have tried running everything I can think of as admin but without luck. I installed node and express on the Windows subsystem Linux with the same error.

[log](https://pastebin.com/PVM67Mtw)

Comment: Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: Please run windows command (or powershell) with admin rights

Comment: Try running `sudo npm install`

Comment: I have already ran everything an admin and root on the cmd and Linux subsystem. Still no luck...